# Right way to remove lp on solana whis raydium sdk ? have a oferflow hm :

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

code snipe : async function removeLiquidity(connection, wallet, poolInfo, amountIn) {
try {
if (!poolInfo) {
throw new Error('Pool-Informationen fehlen.');
}

```
    console.log('Pool-Keys:', poolInfo);

    const poolKeys = {
        id: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.id),
        baseMint: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.baseMint),
        quoteMint: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.quoteMint),
        lpMint: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.lpMint),
        programId: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.programId),
        authority: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.authority),
        openOrders: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.openOrders),
        targetOrders: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.targetOrders),
        baseVault: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.baseVault),
        quoteVault: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.quoteVault),
        withdrawQueue: poolInfo.withdrawQueue ? new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.withdrawQueue) : null,
        lpVault: poolInfo.lpVault ? new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.lpVault) : null,
        marketVersion: poolInfo.marketVersion,
        marketProgramId: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.marketProgramId),
        marketId: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.marketId),
        marketAuthority: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.marketAuthority),
        marketBaseVault: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.marketBaseVault),
        marketQuoteVault: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.marketQuoteVault),
        marketBids: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.marketBids),
        marketAsks: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.marketAsks),
        marketEventQueue: new web3.PublicKey(poolInfo.marketEventQueue),
        baseDecimals: poolInfo.baseDecimals,
        quoteDecimals: poolInfo.quoteDecimals,
        lpDecimals:  poolInfo.lpDecimals,
    }

    // Überprüfen Sie die Anzahl der Dezimalstellen und den Betrag
    if (!Number.isInteger(poolInfo.lpDecimals) || isNaN(amountIn) || amountIn <= 0) {
        throw new Error('Ungültige Dezimalstellen oder Betrag.');
    }

    // Konvertieren Sie den Eingabebetrag in die kleinste Einheit
    const amountInBigNumber = new BigNumber(amountIn)
        .multipliedBy(new BigNumber(1).pow(poolInfo.lpDecimals));

    // Stellen Sie sicher, dass der Betrag nicht zu groß ist
    if (amountInBigNumber.isGreaterThan(BigNumber.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)) {
        throw new Error('Betrag ist zu groß.');
    }

    // Erstellen Sie ein TokenAmount-Objekt
    const amountInTokenAmount = new TokenAmount(
        amountInBigNumber.toString(), // Konvertieren Sie den Betrag in einen String
        poolInfo.lpDecimals,

    );

    console.log("Betrag in der kleinstmöglichen Einheit:", amountInTokenAmount);

  // Pass the TokenAmount object to the function
  const { transaction, signers } = await Liquidity.makeRemoveLiquidityInstructionSimple({
  connection,
  poolKeys: poolKeys, // Ensure poolKeys are set up correctly
  userKeys: {
  owner: wallet.publicKey,
  payer: wallet.publicKey,
  lpTokenAccount: wallet.publicKey // This should be the user's LP token account address
},
 amountIn: amountInTokenAmount
 });

// Send the transaction
const signedTransaction = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [wallet, ...signers],
    { commitment: 'confirmed' }
);

  console.log(`Liquidity removed. Transaction signature: ${signedTransaction}`);
```

} catch (error) {
console.error('Error removing liquidity:', error);
}
}

my error : Error: decimals overflow (code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, module=entity/amount, version=1.1.0-beta.6)
at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\tobib\Desktop\removeauto\node_modules@raydium-io\raydium-sdk\lib\cjs\common\logger.js:175:23)
at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\tobib\Desktop\removeauto\node_modules@raydium-io\raydium-sdk\lib\cjs\common\logger.js:184:20)
at Logger.assert (C:\Users\tobib\Desktop\removeauto\node_modules@raydium-io\raydium-sdk\lib\cjs\common\logger.js:196:14)
at TokenAmount.toFixed (C:\Users\tobib\Desktop\removeauto\node_modules@raydium-io\raydium-sdk\lib\cjs\entity\amount.js:105:16)
at Function. (C:\Users\tobib\Desktop\removeauto\node_modules@raydium-io\raydium-sdk\lib\cjs\liquidity\liquidity.js:465:109)
at Generator.next ()
at C:\Users\tobib\Desktop\removeauto\node_modules@raydium-io\raydium-sdk\lib\cjs\liquidity\liquidity.js:8:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (C:\Users\tobib\Desktop\removeauto\node_modules@raydium-io\raydium-sdk\lib\cjs\liquidity\liquidity.js:4:12)
at Function.makeRemoveLiquidityInstructionSimple (C:\Users\tobib\Desktop\removeauto\node_modules@raydium-io\raydium-sdk\lib\cjs\liquidity\liquidity.js:460:16) {
reason: 'decimals overflow',
code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR'
}